# flows in network equality

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,A)$ be a graph and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb R_{\ge0}$ a flow on the graph. Additionally, let $c:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a capacity function, which means : $f\le c$ for all $e\in A$

Proof that $$\sum_{a\in\delta^{out}(s)}f(a)-\sum_{a\in\delta^{in}(s)}f(a) =\sum_{a\in\delta^{in}(t)}f(a)-\sum_{a\in\delta^{out}(t)}f(a) $$

where  $\delta^{in}(v):=\{(v,w):w\in V\}$ and $\delta^{out}(v):=\{(w,v):w\in V\}$ and $s$ is the source and $t$ is the sink.

By our definition a flow is a function on the edges. $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb R_{\ge0}$ such that the flow property holds for every vertex $v$ which is not $s$ or $t$.

Flow property: $\sum_{a\in\delta^{out}(v)}f(a)-\sum_{a\in\delta^{in}(v)}f(a)=0$ for all $v\in V, v\neq s,t$

Can anyone give me a hint for this problem ?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: It would help if you could state the definition of a "flow", according to your textbook.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : I added the definition. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
0 = \sum_{a \in A}f(a) - \sum_{a \in A} f(a) = 
\sum_{v \in V} \sum_{a \in \delta^{out}(v)} f(a) - \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{a \in \delta^{in}(v)} f(a)
\\ = 
\sum_{v \in V} \left[\sum_{a \in \delta^{out}(v)} f(a) - \sum_{a \in \delta^{in}(v)} f(a)\right]
$$